# Unity Gizmo Size

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making some custom gizmos for my objects in Unity. I want them to work with the 2d and 3d-size setting in the Unity editor. Where do I get this value so I can use it in my script?

[image]

Comment: I found the same question posted last year in Unity Answers. http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/266638/find-current-scale-of-3d-gizmos.html But there is no answer...

Comment: Aha, that didn't come up in me searches. Pity there's no answer :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Gizmos.DrawIcon.html it should be automatic. Otherwise you can try http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/HandleUtility.GetHandleSize.html to get a correct size.